# How to use the same variables but with different values in other different functions?

Tags: php

I need to use the same variables from a given function, in other different functions but with different variable values for each function in part.

In the following example I want to use some image parameters like "width", "height" and "alt" so that each image used in different functions have different parameters. Here's what I mean (pseudo codes):

```
function my_image_with_parameters() {

    if first_function() { // pseudo if statement
        $width  = '350';
        $height = '165';
        $alt    = 'Some alt';

    } elseif second_function() { // pseudo elseif statement
        $width  = '600';
        $height = '400';
        $alt    = 'Another alt';
    }

    return '<img src="http://someurl.com/image.png" width="' .$width . '" height="' .$height . '" alt="' .$alt . '" />';

}

function first_function() {

    echo my_image_with_parameters();

}

function second_function() {

    echo my_image_with_parameters();

}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're after, but you can name variables whatever you want within your functions. It doesn't matter if they have the same names as others, they are locked to the scope of the function unless you declare them as global by doing `global $a;`

Comment: You might want to look at [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
function my_image_with_parameters($width, $height, $alt)
{
    return '<img src="http://someurl.com/image.png" width="' .$width . '" height="' .$height . '" alt="' .$alt . '" />';
}

my_image_with_parameters(350, 165, 'alt');
my_image_with_parameters(600, 400, 'other alt');
```

Functions can take arguments. You pass the arguments when you call the function. The arguments can vary with each function call.

Comment: I admire you guys for the great hobby you have and for the great solutions provided. Given that my php skills level (as you guessed) is far below your levels, it's hard to choose an answer that I consider the most correct one so I chose the answer that best fits with my requirement. Thank you all!

Comment: Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try something like this?

```
function my_image_with_parameters($size = 'small') {

    if ($size == 'small') { 
        $width  = '350';
        $height = '165';
        $alt    = 'Small image';

    } elseif ($size == 'big') { 
        $width  = '600';
        $height = '400';
        $alt    = 'Big image';
    }

    return '<img src="http://someurl.com/image.png" width="' .$width . '" height="' .$height . '" alt="' .$alt . '" />';

}


echo my_image_with_parameters('small');
echo my_image_with_parameters('big');
```

Comment: This could fill with lots of if statements. Why not just pass in each variable as an argument.

Comment: Because sometimes you don't want to remember all the allowed parameters for every function call. Functions don't only process things but can also remember things.

Comment: I disagree. If statements within a function that are based on an argument is poor design. I can't find any reason I would choose your solution. How would I know what arguments are valid? Suppose you add a 'medium' option, you have to alter your function which could belong to a third party library. If your function has a lot of arguments, this is where documentation helps. Although they shouldnt have a huge amount anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is what classes are for. You define some variables in a class, then each instance of that class can have different values in the variables. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    public $width;
    public $height;
    public $alt;

    public function __construct($width, $height, $alt) {
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->alt = $alt;
    }

    public function returnImage() {
        return '<img src="http://someurl.com/image.png" width="' .$this->width . '" height="' .$this->height . '" alt="' .$this->alt . '" />';
    }

}

$firstClass = new MyClass('350', '165', 'Some alt');
echo $firstClass->returnImage();
$secondClass = new MyClass('600', '400', 'Another alt');
echo $secondClass->returnImage();
```

Comment: Based on the knowledge that can be assumed in the question, this is probably overkill. The concept of functions is still new to the poster.

Comment: @Alex I'm assuming the user is posting a much simplified version of his issue, given how he was struggling to describe it initially. But yes, if all you want to do is return an image with different dimensions and alt tag then this is overkill.

Comment: @alex I think, you should not only post answers that comply with the assumed knowledge of the questioner. The questioner can choose for himself what his preferred answer is